# How to get a right side axis in QML

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qml

I want dynamically change LineSeries in a QML ChartView. I'm using Qt 5.7
For this purpose, I have a variable 'updateChart', which triggers the replacement of existing LineSeries, using removeAllSeries() and createSeries()

Sometimes, a LineSeries needs to be displayed using a secondary axis (right axis).
The ChartView createSeries() doesn't allow to assign a right axis to a LineSeries, and from the documentation I cannot find an alternative.

Additionally, you need to have already an axis before calling the createSeries method.
Therefor I have declared 3 axes (X, Y left, Y right) in the ChartView for using them in the createSeries call. The min/max values are modified in another view and kept in the 'chartContext'.
After creation, I change the axisY to axisYRight.

The problem is that my ChartView displays the same axis (min/max values) on both sides. When I change one of the minima/maxima, it updates to that last value, even mixing the minimum from the left axis with the maximum from the right axis.

How can I avoid this ?
Below is my (shortened) code :
chartContext and dataModel are C++ contexts

```
ChartView 
{
  id: linechart;
  anchors.fill: parent;

  property var updateChart: chartContext.updateChart;

  title: chartContext.chartTitle;
  antialiasing: true;

  ValueAxis {
      id: xAxis;
      min: chartContext.minXAxis;
      max: chartContext.maxXAxis;           
  }
  ValueAxis {
      id: yAxis;
      min: chartContext.minYAxis;
      max: chartContext.maxYAxis;
  }
  ValueAxis {
      id: yAxis2;
      min: chartContext.minYAxis2;
      max: chartContext.maxYAxis2;
  }

  onUpdateChartChanged: {
      linechart.removeAllSeries();

      for (var i = 0; i < dataModel.numberOfSeries; ++i) {          
          var lineSeries;
          if (dataModel.axisLocation(i) == "Right") {
              lineSeries = linechart.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, dataModel.getYLabel(i), xAxis);
              lineSeries.axisYRight = yAxis2;
          }
          else {
              lineSeries = linechart.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, dataModel.getYLabel(i), xAxis, yAxis);
          }         
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are chartContext and dataModel?

Comment: I should have explained this better :
- chartContext is a C++ class containing all the settings for the chart (managed and modified by other classes)
- dataModel contains the data for all the lineseries (also coming from other classes)